# Why don't support the type of imported file in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, file, cryptography, document

I'm the developer of iOS. I'm currently making a cryptographic wallet. Problems are not supported when loading `keystore` file types. I saved the data type in the `Info.list` file as `public.data` to broaden the scope. I could choose a file but I don't pass it when I load it. What's the problem?

**DocumentBrowserViewController.swift**

```swift
class DocumentBrowserViewController : UIDocumentBrowserViewController, UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate {
...
    func presentDocument(at documentURL: URL) throws {


        // Start accessing a security-scoped resource.
        guard documentURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
            throw IXError.fileAcessFailed
        }


        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let documentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController

        documentViewController.document = Document(fileURL: documentURL)


        present(documentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        Log.Debug(documentURL)
         defer { documentURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
    }
```

**Document.swift**

```swift
import UIKit


class Document: UIDocument {


    var fileData: Data?

    var filesText: ****.Wallet?

    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {


        Log.Debug("**********************************************************")
        if typeName == "public.data" {

            if let content = filesText {


                let data = content
                return data

            } else {
                return Data()
            }

        } else {
            Log.Debug("**********************************************************")
            return Data()
        }

    } // end func contents

    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?) throws {


        if let fileType = typeName {


            if fileType == "public.png" || fileType == "public.jpeg" { // .jpg not recognized


                if let fileContents = contents as? Data {

                    fileData = fileContents

                }


            } else if fileType == "public.data" {


                if let fileContents = contents as? ***.Keystore {

//                    filesText = String(data: fileContents, encoding: .utf8)
                    filesText = ***.Wallet.init(keystore: fileContents)
                }

            } else {
                Log.Debug("**********************************************************")
                print("File type unsupported.") // Keystore file here
            }

        } // end if let fileType = typeName

    } // end func load

    public var state: String {

        switch documentState {

        case .normal:
            return "Normal"
        case .closed:
            return "Closed"
        case .inConflict:
            return "Conflict"
        case .savingError:
            return "Save Error"
        case .editingDisabled:
            return "Editing Disabled"
        case .progressAvailable:
            return "Progress Available"

        default:
            return "Unknown"

        }

    } // end public var state

} // end class Document
```

**MainController.swift**

```swift
        document?.open(completionHandler: { (success) in

            if success {
                if self.document?.fileType == "public.png" || self.document?.fileType == "public.jpeg" {


//                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: (self.document?.fileData)!)
                    Log.Debug("#################################################")
                    print("\(String(describing: self.document?.fileData))")
                    Log.Debug("#################################################")

                    // #4.5 - If the UIDocument reports that it is a text file...
                } else if self.document?.fileType == "public.data" {


//                    self.textView.text = self.document?.filesText!
                    Log.Debug("**********************************************************")
                    print("\(String(describing: self.document?.filesText))")
                    Log.Debug("**********************************************************")

                }
                Log.Debug("**********************************************************")
                print("\(String(describing: self.document?.fileURL.lastPathComponent))")
                Log.Debug("**********************************************************")
                print("Document state: \((self.document?.state)!)")
                Log.Debug("**********************************************************")

            } else {
                // Make sure to handle the failed import appropriately, e.g., by presenting an error message to the user.
            }

        })
```

**Info.list**

[image: info list]

**FileURL**

> file:///Users/******/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/15169C47-DC68-4B14-B8E8-F75E4108AB7A/data/Containers/Data/Application/499E0805-A3AE-4312-B8B4-55236CFC7BD8/Documents/***/******

**contents:**

> Document.swift load(fromContents:ofType:) [Line:69]  <7b226164
>   64726573 73223a22 64616361 66333634 35393939 36323366 32383535
>   65636262 36393661 ... >

**typename:**

> load(fromContents:ofType:) [Line:71] 
>   Optional("dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8xeqbwtk0w43dbqru0qq30gu4xwsm3g23dg3vwha4xn3pdqmvdqsm0qe6xgqbuqu6ds2mwqmw0q2v2he")

This file does not pass any of the two conditions. My file must pass the '`public.data`' condition. What did I do wrong?

********************************************** Edit *************************

**Info.list**

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>images</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>data</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: `dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8xeqbwtk0w43dbqru0qq30gu4xwsm3g23dg3vwha4xn3pdqmvdqsm0qe6xgqbuqu6ds2mwqmw0q2v2he` is a dynamic UTI, which encodes `"?0=6:1=202z--dacaf3645999623f2855ecbb696a9300d87a2befb89"`. The fact that a dynamic type is being used suggests that something went wrong in the registration of your UTI.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Are you saying the Info.list file is invalid? Which part is wrong?

Comment: I think so, but I don't know what specifically. I remember struggling with getting my UTI registered properly before, but I don't remember the details.

Comment: Could you please share the revenant parts of your `info.plist` (Document types, imported/exported UTIs, etc.), as text? Also, clean up all the excess white space. I understand adding some for visual clarity, but `Document` is practically double-spaced.

Comment: How can I share the info.list file in text? I don't know how because I'm a beginner of iOS.

Comment: @Alexander I uploaded a part of the Info.list. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yep. I probably won't be able to help much, though. What's the file extension on the file you're trying to open?

Comment: The file contains JSON data, as you can see in the question, and does not include any extensions when you create the file.

Comment: The file name of 'FileURL' that you can see in my question is the name that contains the extension.

Comment: I think that could be the problem. Without a file extension, the system doesn't know that your file is a `public.data`. It has no idea what it is, in fact, and synthesizes a dynamic UTI called `dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8xeqbwtk0w43dbqru0qq30gu4xwsm3g23dg3vwha4xn3pdqmvdqsm0qe6xgqbuqu6ds2mwqmw0q2v2he`

Comment: If so, what type should I use to recognize files that do not have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199271/discussion-between-alexander-and-iosbegindevel).

Comment: Okay, I replied to your chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardcoding equality checks against `typeName` is where you went wrong.

As you can see, your file has no file extension. File extensions are the exclusive source of truth that the system uses to determine the Universal Type Identifier (UTI) for a particular file on the system.

Without a file extension, I think the system treats the entire filename as an extension. Given that there is no UTI listed using the extension matching your filename (`0ec6dcc292ec87067774805cb63a4c4694a35e33`), the system does what it always does when it encounters an extension with no registered UTI: it creates a dynamic UTI.

Dynamic UTIs start with `"dyn."`, followed by some seemingly arbitrary characters, which actually are an encoding of the known metadata (file extensions, MIME types, OSType, PastboardTypes, etc.) about an unregistered UTI.

Your mistake stems from doing an exact match against `typeName`:

```
if typeName == "public.data" {
    // ...
}
```

Given that `typeName` has the value `dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8xeqbwtk0w43dbqru0qq30gu4xwsm3g23dg3vwha4xn3pdqmvdqsm0qe6xgqbuqu6ds2mwqmw0q2v2he`, this will obviously fail.

Instead, you should be checking for conformance:

```
import Foundation
import CoreServices

// A helper function to hide away the CFString bridging cruft
func uti(_ uti: String, conformsTo candidateParent: String) -> Bool {
    return UTTypeConformsTo(uti as CFString, candidateParent as CFString)
}

// ...

if uti(typeName, conformsTo: "public.data") {
    // ...
}
```